# How to implement exception handling around MefBootstrapper InitializeModules?

Tags: exception, prism

I have some Prism work.  Specifically, a bootstrapper (MefBootstrapper) that calls InitializeModules.  During one of the modules, an exception is raised, when I re-throw this, I get an exception unhandled.

Unsuccessfully, I have added delegate methods to the exception events, like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
System.Windows.Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += CurrentOnDispatcherUnhandledException;
```

Comment: You do not handle the exception, and then you're asking what to do about an unhandled exception? Why do you (need to) rethrow it in the first place? Couldn't you handle it instead? Either in the module or in the bootstrapper...

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to mark the exception as handled in the event handler attached to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException to keep the application from crashing:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => e.Handled = true;
```

Second, an exception thrown during a given Prism Module initialization can stop other Modules from loading.  To circumvent this you can subclass ModuleManager as follows:

```
public class ErrorHandlingModuleManager : ModuleManager
{
    public ErrorHandlingModuleManager(IModuleInitializer moduleInitializer, IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, ILoggerFacade loggerFacade) : base(moduleInitializer, moduleCatalog, loggerFacade)
    {
    }

    protected override void LoadModulesThatAreReadyForLoad()
    {
        var initializationExceptions = new List<Exception>();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                base.LoadModulesThatAreReadyForLoad();

                break;
            }
            catch (ModuleInitializeException e)
            {
                initializationExceptions.Add(e);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                initializationExceptions.Add(e);

                break;
            }
        }

        if (initializationExceptions.Any())
            throw new AggregateException(initializationExceptions);
    }
}
```

}

Be sure to register ErrorHandlingModuleManager with your Mef container to override the the default.

Comment: Thank you Brett.  This looks promising, and I will report back my findings once I get back to that area of the app...